# How to delete all objects in Azure Managed Cache Service Except Session Objects

Tags: caching, azure, service

We are using Microsoft Azure Cache service for our cloud service which is having multiple web role and worker role instances. Managed cache is also used for storing user sessions. Everything is configured and works fine.

Is there any way using which we can flush / clear all objects in managed cache service at once? we don't want to remove each object by it's key.
If there is a way to do this, then how can we clear everything except user session objects?

I am aware of API whose documentation says that it clear all objects in cache, but not sure if it works in case of managed cache service?
***Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Clear()***

```
static DataCacheFactoryConfiguration cacheFactoryConfiguration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration("default");

static DataCacheFactory cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(cacheFactoryConfiguration);

static DataCache cache = cacheFactory.GetDefaultCache();

cache.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue by creating another named cache which is dedicated for storing the sessions.
All you need to do is, configure your web application (modify web.config) and let azure distributed cached session provider know the new named cache name.
e.g.

```
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
   <providers>
     <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="dedicatednamedcache" dataCacheClientName="dedicatednamedcache" applicationName="AFCacheSessionState"/>
   </providers>
 </sessionState>
```

so while clearing entire cache, just clear your named cache (default named cache) and not the named cache which is used as session store.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API to achieve this. If you don't specify lifetime for the objects cached they are cleared after 48 hours.

Comment: Thanks for Reply Arvind.

I tried a quick example on console application - pointing to managed cache service and seems like the clear() method of DataCache class works. It does remove all objects associated in each cache regions. 

Now what I am wondering if it works, does it clear all session objects in cache too?

Comment: if you have configured sessionstate to get stored in cache then add an item in session , clear cache and then try retrieving the same item and check.

Comment: Did the very same exercise already.. found that items in the session state are cleared if cache is cleared.

Comment: Oh okay. Then that suits your requirement I guess.

Comment: Indeed it is not. what I expect is the way to clear all objects in cache except session objects.

Comment: That being the case you need to specify lifetime specifically for objects and handle it instead of clearing all cache.

Comment: yeah that's another good workaround but there is a scenario wherein I would need to clear everything in a cache and let the cache rebuild.
I would have liked if the azure would have provided more control on regions in the cache.

Comment: Cache is always handled that way. if u want to clear all you clear all. thats about it. One option you can try is to move your session state to sql azure or any other out of proc store and it won't clash with your cache.